# Why isn't my ViewBag setting available in my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I have the following code in my HomeController's Index action, and the code below it in my layout. When I call up the Home/Index view, the UserName property isn't set, but I know it is set in my controller, as I examine the value with a breakpoint.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData.Add("UserName", User.Identity.Name);
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
@{ 
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    <text>Hello </text>
    @ViewBag.UserName <text> - </text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "LogOff", "Account", null, new { style = "font-weight: bold;" })
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** When I try the following view code, as suggested in answers below, I get a the compilation error: *'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'Display' but appears to have an extension method by that name.*

I wonder if this is not some side effect of my nested layouts? The layout for the view cited is _ThreeColumn, and the layout for the latter is _Layout, set as default in _ViewStart.

Comment: Why not use the User.Identity.Name in the view also?

Comment: @Mika, I started out just using `User.Identity.Name` in the view, then added extras to debug when that wasn't appearing either.

Comment: Did you try just doing Hello @User.Identity.name - @Html.ActionLink(...)?

Comment: @Mika, just tried that now, still blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you should consistantly use viewbag or viewdata in both your controller and view, as it makes your code easier to understand.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Username = User.Identity.Name;
    return View();
}
```

The real problem lies with `@Html.Display` you dont need the @ symbol again. It should be as follows:

```
@ViewBag.UserName <text> - </text>
```

Comment: Isn't the ViewBag just a dynamic accessor for the ViewData dictionary?

Comment: Yea, good point, so the problem lies solely in the @Html.Display code.

Answer (score 3):

change     `@Html.Display("@ViewBag.UserName")`   to `@ViewBag.UserName`

also you can do below for more readability (inside controller)

```
ViewBag.UserName=  User.Identity.Name;
```

---

@variableName in razor views automatically produces html encoded text. See below

```
---A razor view start---

    @{
       string name= "<b>Praveen</b>";       
    }

    Hello @name     
    <br><br>
   Hello  @Html.Raw(name)
---A razor view end---
```

--output----

Hello  `<b>Praveen!!</b>`    ---automatically html encoded

Hello **Praveen**            ---html produced as it is